# using crystalreportviewer for windows 10

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, windows-10

i have a project and using "crystalreportviewer" control, to view .rpt files.
my complied project, executes correctly in my PC and other pc with windows 7.
But in windows 8.1 and 10 , it has this error:

```
crystaldecisions.crystalreports.engine.reportdocument' threw an exception
```

I installed CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_3.msi and CRRedist2005_x86.msi .
But it dosn't show the report .

Please Help me, what do i do?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the aspnet_client folder.
Rename the folder ''4_0_30319" to "4_6_79" .
It will work.

Comment: But, my Project is a windows local App! (.exe)